# PHP my checking in the if statement to re-populate a checked button is not working

Tags: php

I recently found out how to re-populate checked radio buttons.. but Im not sure why right now its jumping to re-populate the last one of them even if the checked is the first one. 
I can't find my mistake, I hope some can.. Thanks lots..

```
 <tr>
        <td class="right text">Title:</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Mr." <?php if (isset($_POST['sex']) == "Mr.") echo "checked"; ?>>Mr.</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Mrs." <?php if (isset($_POST['sex']) == "Mrs.") echo "checked"; ?>>Mrs.</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Ms." <?php if (isset($_POST['sex']) == "Ms.") echo "checked"; ?>>Ms.</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this for all three radio buttons.

```
<?php if ( isset($_POST['sex']) && $_POST['sex'] == "Mr.") echo "checked"; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your test is wrong. You're testing to see if the POST field "sex" is set. Then you're saying "Is this equivalent to this value?" So you're taking a boolean and comparing it to a string. So none of your tests will work.

The best way to do this is to move your test into an array. It means less tests and cleaner HTML

```
<?php
$data = array('Mr.' => null, 'Mrs.' => null, 'Ms.' => null);
if(isset($_POST['sex'])) $data[$_POST['sex']] = ' checked="checked"';
?>
<td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Mr."<?php echo $data['Mr.'] ?> />Mr.</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Mrs."<?php echo $data['Mrs.'] ?> />Mrs.</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Ms."<?php echo $data['Ms.'] ?> />Ms.</td></tr>
```